# How implement rest jersey method that receives one or more String and return a String

Tags: java, rest, jersey-2.0

for eg.
How implement rest jersey method that receives one or more String and return a String
using this way or another way

```
@GET
@Path("/autenticate/{mail}/{passwd}")
@Produces("text/plain")
public String autenticate(@PathParam("mail") String mail, 
@PathParam("passwd") String   passwd) {
 return "testok";
}        

public String autenticateUser(String mail, String passw) 
throws ClientErrorException {
    WebTarget resource = webTarget;
    resource = resource.path(
    java.text.MessageFormat.format("autenticate/{0}/{1}", 
    new Object[]{mail, passw}));
    System.out.println(resource.getUri());
    System.out.println(resource);
    return resource.request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).get(String.class);
```

}

these above code return

```
javax.ws.rs.InternalServerErrorException: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.convertToException(JerseyInvocation.java:929)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.translate(JerseyInvocation.java:770)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.access$500(JerseyInvocation.java:90)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$2.call(JerseyInvocation.java:671)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:422)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:667)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:396)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:296)
```

Comment: Check #2 here http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jax-rs-pathparam-example/

Basically try to return a jersey Response, rather than String

If you put a breakpoint @ return "testok"; does it enter ?

Answer (score 0):

What you have should work.  I tried it in jetty (as opposed to glassfish), and it worked fine.  How are you attempting to call it?  It should be http(s):://autenticate/something/something_else .

Note that your second method isn't doing anything, since you're simply returning "testok."

Comment: this is just an example, the code inside the method was causing javax.ws.rs.InternalServerErrorException: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error, i solved this after few minutes i post, thank you any way.